# Sending array in header with Get, Put and Post methods

Tags: php, curl

everyone!
my question is about HTTP headers and how to send my array to server.
my array is :

```
$postdata = array(
    'user' => $user,
    'timestamp' => $timestamp,
    'hash' => $hash
);
```

i want to send my array with curl() to server but in header, and i use slim in my server.
my client side is :

```
$url = 'localhost/test';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_url, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $postdata);

$response = curl_exec($ch);

echo $response;
curl_close($ch);
```

My server side is :

```
require('slim/slim.php');

\slim\slim::registerAutoloader();

$app = new \slim\slim(array('debug' => true, 'mode' => 'development'));
$app->contentType('application/json;charset=utf-8');
$app-get('test', 'mockup');
$app->run();

function mockup() {/* ... */}
```

Comment: What's the problem with your code? Is `CURLOPT_url` a copying error, or do you have that mistake in the real code?

Comment: Are you asking how to read the custom headers in the server code?

Comment: thats my second question. but now i dont know how to make a header with my array-data

Comment: You might want to look at documentation for what exactly `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` accepts.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just post it instead of trying to create new headers?

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
```

Then on the other side just get your data from the `$_POST` array

Comment: Actually i did it with POSTFIELD befor, but i need now to send my array with this three methods in header.